# fast way to delete entries of STL vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, stdvector

I have a vector of pointers which I want to delete, but iterating over the vector and calling `delete` for each element is quite slow. Is there a faster way?

Unfortunately I really need to store pointers, since I use a virtual superclass. Simplified, the class structure looks something like this:

```
class VirtualSuperClass
{
protected:
    SomeType m_someMember;
    // ...
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Subclass_1 : public VirtualSuperClass
{
protected:
    SomeType m_someSubclassMember;
    // ...
public:
    virtual void doSomething() { /* do something*/ }
};

class Subclass_2 : public VirtualSuperClass
{
protected:
    SomeType m_someOtherSubclassMember;
    // ...
public:
    virtual void doSomething() { /* do something else*/ }
}
```

In my main method I fill a vector of pointers of the superclass and call the function `doSomething()` for every element.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<VirtualSuperClass*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new Subclass_1());
    vec.push_back(new Subclass_2());
    vec.push_back(new Subclass_2());
    vec.push_back(new Subclass_1());
    // and so on, about 40,000 elements (not really done with .push_back :) ) ...

    // this actually runs in an application loop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        vec[i]->doSomething();
    }

    // ...

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        delete vec[i];     // <-- pretty slow for large number of elements
        vec[i] = NULL;
    }
    vec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you store `shared_ptr<VirtualSuperClass>` rather than pointers then the compiler will take care of this for you.

Comment: @JonathanPotter:  It won't be any less slow however, and I think that's the issue here.

Comment: No point calling `clear()` and setting pointers to `NULL` after `delete` if your vector is going out of scope in the next line. Just do `delete`s (or use smart pointers and don't) and return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you may be looking for is a custom allocator for the classes you allocate - this way you can effectively get and release memory to the system in bulk rather then in tiny fragments - it's probably the only solution for improving "overall" performance of this system without modifying it (which given your bottleneck sure looks like a good idea ;) ).

Comment: Assuming there are no complex tasks in the destructors and it's really deallocation that is a bottleneck.

Comment: Correct and given the data we have I think this is the case (ie. the delete line pointed as the bottleneck not one of the destructor bodies etc)

Comment: @RnR: Writing an allocator is something I have never done before, but it sounds interresting. I will try it out.

Comment: @RnR actually I am a bit stuck here. When I write a custom allocator for the pointers in my vector I am able to control how my pointers are allocated, but how does that help me allocating the actual objects in a single chunk of data? Or did I understand your solution wrong? I also tried overloading the 'new' operator, but then I have the problem that when my chunk of memory gets too small I have to reallocate it, and all the old pointers will have to be updated :(

Comment: Yes - writing custom allocators is not easy. The point was that you need to have a new that cuts out the appropriate amount of memory from some bigger chunk of data, then you need to consider managing those bigger chunks etc. I googled a bit and see that we have something that seems to solve this problem in boost - maybe you can give it a try? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html

Comment: Hm, I will have to create a pool for every subclass, but it should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Any *correct* solution is going to boil down to doing a `delete` on each pointer.  Since you have profiled your code and identified that as being the bottleneck, then I would look for a solution that moves the `delete` to another thread.

This could be done by:

1. Create a worker thread that `delete`s pointers passed in
2. Remove the pointers from the vector and copy them to another vector, owned by the worker thread
3. Kick off the worker thread job, let it delete the pointers

This isn't going to be any faster than your current solution in terms of pure CPU time (and in fact can be slower depending on how you do it), but it will move the heavy lifting out of your main thread.

Comment: If you are going down this road then why bother with copying and not swapping/moving the vector contents into the other thread?

Comment: @Nobody: Sure, that seems quite reasonable.  You'd have to ensure that the vector where you're moving to is locked down, however.

Comment: @JohnDibling: This mehtod would work in the cases when I delete the memory when I still want to work with my program. But it will not decrese the time the program needs for the final cleanup, where I need it for. With my current implementation stopping the program takes about five minutes.

Comment: @maddin45:  You didn't hear this from me, but if you simply don't `delete` something it will be reclaimed at app shutdown under both linux and windows.

Comment: @JohnDibling: That could help, but our professor makes us use a tool to check for memory leaks and this would be a big leak ;)

Comment: @JohnDibling - unless what you want reclaimed is not memory but the destructor releases a system wide resource (say a lock file) or you decide to implement a demon, keep the process alive and process the requests a thousand times before closing the process - and all of a sudden things blow up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another method that *might* improve performance is to use a kind of memory pool, in which you allocate one big raw buffer up front, and then placement-`new` each individual object within that buffer.

This has the potential of improving performance because, although you still have to destroy each pointer, that destruction is done via calling the destructor directly rather than `delete`ing it.  This avoids having to go down to the system's memory manager, and that avoidance is where the potential lies for performance improvements.

There are significant caveats to this approach however, and I wouldn't recommend it in any but the most extreme cases.  Among the caveats is the onerous responsibility you place on yourself to manage your own memory.

Comment: I thought about this, but it would require restructuring much of my code.