# Destroying tree structured vectors of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, unique-ptr, destruction

I have been migrating my code to use std::unique_ptr.

When I had to decide about one class which had a tree hierarchy, I decided to let the object own their children, so that removing an object from the tree would delete it.
However I have noticed that in complex hierarchies of thousands of elements destroying it is really slow. Like, unbelievably slow.

So is it simply advised not to nest vectors of unique pointers, and should I switch to a flat layout of the unique_ptr, and just keep regular pointers in the tree ?
I am imagining that it may be a well known fact that this is a no-go, but it is puzzling me as I had a hard time finding literature on this specific detail.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Element
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>> mChildren;
};
```

UPDATE : After a long hestitation whether or not to delete my question, I noticed my problem is quite similar to this one :
[fast way to delete entries of STL vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913850/fast-way-to-delete-entries-of-stl-vector-of-pointers)

With the addition that the process is even slower with the tree structure. `unique_ptr` doesn't seem to be responsible here after all.

I wrote a piece of code to investigate it

- destroying 60 000 elements, `unique_ptr`, flat layout takes about 5 seconds
- destroying 60 000 elements, `unique_ptr`, tree layout takes about 8 seconds

Without unique_ptr the times are only marginally lower.

So the actual problem I'm facing is just that it's slow to delete 60 000 things in a row.
Then I imagine my solutions are similar the ones in the linked question :

- Pool memory for elements that I know I'm gonna delete in batchs, but it's said to be very cumbersome and prone to grave errors
- Have a worker thread do it, that is it will stay slow but will not hinder the main thread anymore

I'm technically unsavy as to how to properly execute both, but I suppose it will educate me.

Comment: Post a complete test case that demonstrates the issue you are observing. _unbelievably slow_ is not quantitative enough.

Comment: In addition to Maxim's comment, given what you've shown I see no reason why it should be so "unbelievably slow." The data structure memory layout looks fine - maybe not optimal, but not horrible either.

Comment: I just ran a quick test with a vector of 10,000 elements, both with plain pointers using new/delete and with `unique_ptr`. With MSVC12 debug mode, `unique_ptr` is about 5 times longer. On release, it's about 1.4 times longer.

Comment: I am sorry, if I had a test case I would post it. It's not easy to extract one from the application. It's not just one vector with 10 000 elements, but a tree with maybe 1 / 500 / 10 000 / 20 000 elements total on 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th levels. The number will really vary as it depends on the user but in my current case that's about the numbers I have. I was guessing the tree structure is what makes it so slow compared to a flat one which is already slower as Steve demonstrated. I am gonna try to extract a test case soon.

Comment: It probably mainly depends on what you put in your destructor, do you have a heavy operation within it ?

Comment: Consider using Boost.Pool, either as a singleton allocator, or using a per-parent pool that owns its children (only if you never move children between parents)

Comment: @Useless This sounds perfect, I'm gonna look into it and implement it in the test to measure the difference

Comment: @Useless So I implemented a quick test with the root having a `boost::pool`, and the results in debug mode where not quicker (profiling indicated a lot of time was spent deallocating the std::vectors, and roughly the more total elements with children, the more time it took). However in release mode the speed is at least four times better with `boost::pool`. So I assume vector deallocation ist much worse in debug mode. In short using boost::pool shifts the bottleneck to deallocation of the vectors which is still quite better.